# inapp purchase - can't load products

Tags: in-app-purchase

i want to enable some inapp purchases in my new app. but i'm not able to load the informations from the store.
i'm quite sure, that i configured everything all right.. the bundle id seems to be the same at all 3 places (APP ID @ provisining portal, bundle id in iTunes Connect and the Provision Cer). i'm also able to upload the binaries to apple.

EDIT:
fixed the problem by myself. 
 for me helped 2 things in combination:

- remove "rejected" status via uploading the binaries again
- don't use a jailbroken device

But in FAQ 6 are some more reasons for this problem listed:

- You did not complete all the financial requirements (see the "Contracts, Tax, and Banking Information" section of this document).
- You did not use an explicit App ID.
- You did not use the Provisioning Profile associated with your explicit App ID.
- You did not use the correct product identifier in your code. See Technical Q&A, QA1329, 'In App Purchase Product Identifiers' for more information about product identifiers.
- You did not clear your In App Purchase products for sale in iTunes Connect.
- You might have modified your products, but these changes are not yet available to all the App Store servers.

If you or App Review rejected your most recent binary in iTunes Connect.
hope this will help some more of you.

Comment: at the moment i saw, that all 8 products are waiting for review. could this be the reason or doesn't this matter for sandbox testing? (http://bit.ly/xr95xm)